# How do I change the color behind the actionbar which appears when using rounded top corners?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've followed [Googles theme guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#StyleExample) when customising the Actionbar. I´ve also added rounded top corners on the `ActionBar`. The problem is a white color appearing behind the corners where they are rounded.

This is my activity main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

My styles.xml

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme">
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

This is my actionbar_theme.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#ffc71e"
        android:endColor="#d09e07"
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="270"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#333" >
    </stroke>
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp">
    </corners>
</shape>
```

How do I change the background of the base application. I want it black.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and this solution works for me. Just change the colorBackground of your activity theme's style.

`<item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/black</item>`

This is my activity in manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

My theme style xml file, styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```